# Java library for netflow

Tags: java, swing, netflow

Is there a Java library for Netflow?  I need to be able to objectify flows for analysis.  (I really need to support sflow, too, but one hurdle at a time.)  I found a project called "jflow" that has classes for Netflow v5 and v6, but I need to support 7 and 9 as well.

All of my googling has brought me nothing.  Does anyone know of a library?  Has anyone written their own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is [Java NetFlow Collect-Analyzer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jnca/) as well. It supports v7 and v9 as well as previous versions.

Comment: I found this, and have NO IDEA how to use it.  I can't find any documentation.  The binary release seems to only support configuring it to dump flow data into a database - which is not helpful for me.  If there is a way to use this to get objectified flows I can work in my code I would LOVE some help with getting that done.

Comment: Thanks user1394965 for your answer, and thanks to SAN3 as well.  I'm marking this one as the accepted answer since Styx uses the same classes from this project for objectifying flows.  Neither of these provided something I could "just use".  But, with access to the source and some modifications I can create something useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another java library called Styx is another Netflow Collector and Analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Scala library](https://github.com/wasted/netflow), which presumably means it could be invoked from Java.  But that's not specifically documented, nor have I attempted to.